# Data attribute name with digits

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it expected that for

```
<div data-foo-42="bar"></div>
```

div the `div.data()` would be an empty object?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nWCKt/

What are the requirements for `data-` attributes names?

Created a ticket in jquery bug tracker: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14376

Comment: `A custom data attribute is an attribute in no namespace whose name starts with the string "data-", has at least one character after the hyphen, is XML-compatible, and contains no characters in the range U+0041 to U+005A (LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A to LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Z).`

Comment: Using data() you can access the attribute like so: div.data("foo-42") rather than div.attr("div-foo-42") - does that help?

Comment: @Arun P Johny: how my name violates that requirement?

Comment: it looks like a jQuery data issue...

Comment: the data set store the value as `div.get(0).dataset['foo42']`

Comment: @Arun P Johny: actually, I'm not sure I can understand it :-S "and contains no characters in the range U+0041 to U+005A (LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A to LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Z)" --- so it means that `data-A` is an incorrect name?

Comment: @zerkms yes, it is...  because if you have a property like `data-my-name` in html5 data is stored a `myName`... hopefully you understood the conflict

Comment: That's right, @zerkms.  While it might be supported in some places, capital letters are non-standard.

Comment: @zerkms it looks to be a bug in the jQuery data method(in the `dataAttr` method)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like a jquery issue to me. The regex that replaces key is causing the issue when there is a numeric value after a hyphen separator of the attribute (Other than the first hyphen for `data-`). They need a way to identify numeric values that start after the attribute on a multidash data attribute.

Snippet from jquery:

```
function dataAttr( elem, key, data ) {
    // If nothing was found internally, try to fetch any
    // data from the HTML5 data-* attribute
    if ( data === undefined && elem.nodeType === 1 ) {

        var name = "data-" + key.replace( rmultiDash, "-$1" ).toLowerCase(); 

        data = elem.getAttribute( name );

         ....
```

and another one which converts data attrib name to the key used in the above place which actually converts the key to camelcase `rdashAlpha = -([\da-z])`, and the second replacement (`.replace( rdashAlpha, fcamelCase );`) considers a numeric value after a separator to be a part of the prev separator. This probably is the core culprit which ignores numeric start after second dash.

```
camelCase: function( string ) {
        return string.replace( rmsPrefix, "ms-" ).replace( rdashAlpha, fcamelCase );
    },
```

Here key becomes foo42 and while replacing it with rmultiDash (which is /[A-Z]/) becomes foo42 so there  is no attribute with the name `data-foo42` it is `data-foo-42` instead. I think they need to have some identifier (similar to capitalization of the key for the first char after hash) to represent starting numerals after the hash.

```
<div  data-foo-42="bar" data-foo-tfs="tf"></div>
```

returns `{fooYui: "bar"}` skips the first attribute.

```
<div data-foo-d42="bar" data-foo-YUI="bar"></div>
```

returns `{fooD42: "bar", fooYui: "bar"}`

using jquery 1.10.1